# Get Swashbuckle/Swagger route programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using Swashbuckle with ASP.NET Core 6. It serves Swagger at `/swagger`.

For diagnostic purposes I need to detect that path programmatically at runtime - i.e. assuming swashbuckle is serving swagger at `/swagger`, then I want to be able to get that path.

I've tried various approaches, but they just give me my own routes. I can't find a way to determine routes added by swashbuckle.

I tried:

```cs
// inject IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>
// ...
var routes = _endpointDataSources.SelectMany(source => source.Endpoints);
```

and:

```cs
var routes = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>()
  .ActionDescriptors
  .Items.Where(x => x.AttributeRouteInfo != null)
  .Select(x => x.AttributeRouteInfo?.Template);
```

In both cases it enumerates all of my routes - whether they are from RazorPages or WebApi. But the swagger route is not included, even though it is running.

How do I get that path?

Comment: are you using `app.UseSwagger();` or `app.MapSwagger()`. in case useswagger it does not create any endpoint but a middleware so when you call /swagger it checks for request and returns swagger document. but in case of MapSwagger it actually creates endpoint.

Comment: @CodingMytra Thanks! I am using `UseSwagger`, so your explanation makes sense. I wonder whether I can just swap from the one to the other without breaking something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @lonix comment, Converting to Ans.

In case UseSwagger(), it does not create any endpoint but a middleware so when you call "/swagger", it checks request for swagger document and returns swagger document if found true. but in case of MapSwagger() it actually creates endpoint.

and yes you can swap it without breaking anything.